# Gaussian Markov Random Fields - Conditional distribution from jointly gaussian with given precision matrix

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, precision-matrix

Suppose I have jointly normal random vectors $[\bf{v_1}, \ldots, \bf{v_K}]$' with mean $ \bf{M}$ and joint block tridiagonal precision matrix $ \bf{P}$:

$$ \bf{M}= \begin{bmatrix}\bf{\mu_1} \\\ldots \\  \bf{\mu_K} 
 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \bf{P}= \begin{bmatrix}\bf{P}_{11} &  \bf{P}_{12}  & \bf{0} & \bf{0}\\ \bf{P}_{21} & \bf{P}_{22} & \ddots & \bf{0} \\\bf{0} & \ddots & \ddots & \bf{P}_{KK-1} \\ \bf{0} &  \bf{0} & \bf{P}_{K-1K} & \bf{P}_{KK}  \\\\ 
 \end{bmatrix}  $$

$\bf{v_1}, \ldots,\bf{v_K}$ are all of dimension $N \times 1$. I want to derive the  generic conditional distribution $ \bf{v_n}|\bf{v_{n-1}}$ for $1<n<K$ as a function of the elements of $\bf{M}$ and of the elements of the precision matrix $\bf{P}$.

I am following the approach outlined here [link](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis520/papers/Bishop_2.3.pdf), (equations 2.73 2.75) that in a two random vectors set up shows that the conditional mean and the conditional variance can be written as a  function of the elements of the vector of means and the precision matrix.

I am proceeding as follows:

First, I marginalize all the $\bf{v}_i$'s for $i = 1,\ldots,n-2$ and for $i = n+1,\ldots,K$. Then I derive the mean and the variance of $\bf{v_n}|\bf{v_{n-1}}$ as the article suggests.

Following this approach, I am struggling in finding a general formula for the conditional mean and conditional variance as a function of the elements of the precision matrix .

Is it the right way to proceed?

Comment: The link doesnt work for me, so I am not sure what type of formula you want. Do you care if it contains P^-1 or do you want something more explicit?

Comment: @svendvn yes sorry I fixed the problem with the link. The formula I am looking for is the conditional mean and the conditional variance of a generic random vector conditionally on its predecessor as a function of the elements of the precision matrix and NOT of its inverse.  The fact that this precision matrix implies a markov structure, such that conditionally on its predecessor each random vector is independent of the other random vectors preceding it, should help me, but still the fact that I have to marginalize all the other random vectors gives me other extra terms ...

Comment: Consider the Choleky root $\mathbf {L}$ such that $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^\top$. The matrix $\mathbf{L}$ is block tridiagonal and $\mathbf{e}_i :=  \mathbf{L}_{i,i} \mathbf{v}_i+ \mathbf{L}_{i,i-1} \mathbf{v}_{i-1}$ is a sequence on independent normal r.vs.

Comment: Sorry $\mathbf{e} := \mathbf{L}^\top \mathbf{v}$ which gives $\mathbf{v}_i$ in function of $\mathbf{e}_i$ and $\mathbf{v}_{i+1}$.

Comment: @Yves thanks a lot for the comment. should I obtain the conditional mean and variance by manipulating what you defined as $\bf{e}$ then? could you please clarify the point you made? how?

Comment: The special structure of the precision matrix corresponds to an autoregression. The distribution of $\mathbf{v}_i$ conditional on the other elements only depends on the "neighbouring" $\mathbf{v}_{i-1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{i+1}$. I hastily thought that you were looking for a representation of the vector. Sorry for this confusing comment.

Comment: @Yves yes exactly the random vectors are markov processes. maybe I could exploit your expression to invert just the cholesky factor from $\bf{e} = \bf{L}'\bf{v}$ and see if in the inversion I keep the terms of $\bf{P}$

Comment: @Yves actually I am looking at the representation of the random vector conditionally on its predecessor as a function of the elements in $\bf{P}$ and $\bf{M}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Cholesky root $\mathbf {L}$ such that $\mathbf{P} =
\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^\top$. The matrix $\mathbf{L}$ is block
tridiagonal
$$
   \mathbf{L} =
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{L}_{1,1} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} &     &  & \mathbf{0} \\
   \mathbf{L}_{2,1} & \mathbf{L}_{2,2} & \mathbf{0} &  & & \mathbf{0} \\
           &  & \ddots  & \ddots & & \\
    &  &   & & & \\
          &  &  &   &  \mathbf{L}_{K-1,K-1} & \mathbf{0} \\
       \mathbf{0}  & \mathbf{0}  &  &   &  \mathbf{L}_{K, K-1} & \mathbf{L}_{K,K}
   \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Considering the three first blocks in the order row/columns are blocks we get
$$
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{L}_{1,1} \mathbf{L}_{1,1}^\top & = \mathbf{P}_{1,1}, \\
  \mathbf{L}_{2,1} \mathbf{L}_{1,1}^\top & = \mathbf{P}_{2,1}, \\
  \mathbf{L}_{2,1} \mathbf{L}_{2,1}^\top  + 
     \mathbf{L}_{2,2} \mathbf{L}_{2,2}^\top 
    & = \mathbf{P}_{2,2}. 
  \end{aligned}
$$
So $\mathbf{L}_{1,1}$ is the Cholesky root of $\mathbf{P}_{1,1}$,
then $\mathbf{L}_{2,1} = \mathbf{P}_{2,1}\mathbf{L}_{1,1}^{-\top}$ and then
$\mathbf{L}_{2,2}$ is the Cholesky root of
$\mathbf{P}_{2,2} - \mathbf{L}_{2,1}\mathbf{L}_{2,1}^\top$. More generally
we find
$$
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{L}_{k,k-1} &= \mathbf{P}_{k,k-1}\mathbf{L}_{k-1,k-1}^{-\top},\\
  \mathbf{L}_{k,k} &= \texttt{chol}(\mathbf{P}_{k,k} - 
  \mathbf{L}_{k,k-1}\mathbf{L}_{k,k-1}^\top)
  \end{aligned} 
  \right.
  \qquad k=2, \dots, \, K,
$$
which allows to find the blocks in $\mathbf{L}$ by recursion.

Now let $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} := \mathbf{L}^{\top}\mathbf{v}$ with
block components $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_k$. Then
$$
\text{Cov}(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \mathbf{L}^{\top} \text{Cov}(\mathbf{v}) 
   \mathbf{L} = \mathbf{L}^{\top}\mathbf{P}^{-1}
   \mathbf{L} = \mathbf{L}^{\top}\mathbf{L}^{-\top} \mathbf{L}^{-1}
   \mathbf{L} = 
   \mathbf{I},
$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix.
So the block components $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_k$ are independent normal rv.s.

Let us first assume that $\mathbf{v}$ has mean zero i.e., that
$\mu_k = \mathbf{0}$ for all $k$. By back substitution

$$
  \begin{aligned}
  \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{K} &= \mathbf{L}_{K,K}^{\top} \mathbf{v}_K \\
  \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_j &= \mathbf{L}_{j,j}^\top \mathbf{v}_j +  \mathbf{L}_{j+1,j}^\top \mathbf{v}_{j +1} \qquad j= K-1, \, K-2, \, \dots, \, 1.
  \end{aligned}
$$

So with the observations labelled with the index as a reversed "time"
we get an autoregression $$ \mathbf{v}_j = \boldsymbol{\Phi}_j
\mathbf{v}_{j+1}
    + \mathbf{G}_j \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{j}, \qquad j=K-1, \, K-2,\, \dots, \,1
$$

with $\boldsymbol{\Phi}_j := -\mathbf{L}^{-\top}_{j,j}
\mathbf{L}_{j+1,j}^\top$ and $\mathbf{G}_j :=
\mathbf{L}_{j,j}^{-\top}$. It can indeed be seen that $\mathbf{v}_j$
is uncorrelated with the noise r.vs $\varepsilon_j - \ell$ for $\ell
\geqslant 1$. We have a representation of the sequence or r.vs
$\mathbf{v}_j$ as the solution of a (backward) finite difference
equation. A forward equation could be derived as well. The
representation can be used e.g., to simulate the r.vs $\mathbf{v}_j$.

In the general case where the mean of $\mathbf{v}$ is no longer zero we can
apply the previous derivation to the vector $\mathbf{w}$ with blocks
$\mathbf{w}_k := \mathbf{v}_k - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k$.

The specific sparsity pattern of the precision matrix $\mathbf{P}$
tells that $\mathbf{v}_j$ is correlated with the other r.vs
$\mathbf{v}_\ell$ with $\ell \neq j$ only through the neighbouring
elements $\mathbf{v}_{j-1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_{j+1}$.  An important
general property is that the matrix of partial correlations has the
same sparsity pattern (or "structural zeros") as the precision matrix.

Comment: the derivation is convincing, but what surprises me is that the elements of $ \bf{M}$ do not appear in the autoregressive equation, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I omitted the mean. The answer can be applied to the vector say $\mathbf{w}$ with blocks $\mathbf{v}_k - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k$.